# Catch exit sign from npm script package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, docker-compose, scripting, package.json

is it possible to hook the exit sign of an npm script?

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "docker-compose up && npm start"
}
```

I want to be able to call `docker-compose down` when exiting the script with `ctrl+c`

With a shell script, this is possible by 'trapping' the signed exit 0

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap 'docker-compose down ; echo Stopped ; exit 0' SIGINT

docker-compose up &
npm start

done
```

I would rather not use a shell script so it can be run on other OS than Unix like systems.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use your initial script in an npm script (package.json) when running docker compose in the background (-d).

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "up": "trap 'docker-compose down ; echo Stopped ; exit 0' SIGINT; docker-compose up -d && npm start"
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would rather not use a shell script so it can be run on other OS than Unix like systems.

You can write your script in Node.js to make it compatible with any OS where `npm start` can be run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';
const childProcess = require('child_process');

childProcess.spawnSync('docker-compose', ['up'], { stdio: 'inherit'});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('SIGINT caught, running docker-compose down');
  childProcess.spawnSync('docker-compose', ['down'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
  process.exit(0);
});

console.log('go ahead, press control-c');
childProcess.spawnSync('npm', ['start'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Comment: I like the idea, so I guess that there is not an option from package.json directly?